# R.id cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Tags: android

This is a simple code to show a simple listview with images and text. its giving two errors. 
 at statement,

```
int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt}; //error: flag cannot be resolved or is not a fied
lv = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview); //error: listview cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

hope you will accomodate me!
regards

```
 package com.example.amjad_3;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     // Array of strings storing country names
     String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistan",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
        };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
        int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.india,
        R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.srilanka,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.nepal,
        R.drawable.afghanistan,
        R.drawable.nkorea,
        R.drawable.skorea,
        R.drawable.japan
        };

       // Array of strings to store currencies

        ListView lv;
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

          for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);

            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
          SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,          R.layout.listview, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        lv = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview); 

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just asking. Does R.id.flag and R.id.listview exsit in R.layout.activity_main? Also, have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: is it like this in your xml? -->  "<ListView android:id="@+id/android:listview" />"

Comment: yes of course, r.id.flag and r. id. listview exist in R.layout.activity_main...

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

Buddy You have done mapping wrong between `from array` and `to array` in your code..
As your `from array` has 3 objects and your `to array` has 2 objects in it.. 
So this exception is raised..

Just Change this lines in your code & run your project again:

```
// Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Your Project is not properly Build.

Check if Eclipse has generated your `R.java` file in `gen` folder.

If not, check error in your `res` files, correct it and build your project.

If `R.java` file is present in `gen` folder,check if your have imported it correctly in your java file.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse try just going to Project-> Clean... then either chose all projects on your workspace or just the one you are currently working on and hit ok. This will rebuild your project along with dealing with some other issues in android that can sometimes cause the R.java file to not update after you change an xml layoutfile.